# Overwriting data in a file starting from a given line in java

Tags: java, file-io

I want to specifically overwrite data in a file starting from a given line.

Suppose that I find out that I have to write some data in the file from line x ( I have already found x) . How would I overwrite everything after there.

Also is there a function that would directly take my line and string and overwrite the file.

Comment: your best bet would be to load each line of the file into an array. Overwrite the parts of the array you don't want then overwrite the file with your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate approach would be, read the file line by line by scanner class (as described below), store those lines into any variable, say, arraylist, then appennd your new string once you have read the lines and write the whole list into a new file.

Example:

```
File file = new File("file.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\n");
String line = scanner.next();
//Store in the list
//Append the new lines
//Write the whole list into a new file
```

Comment: The problem for me is that i'll be reading a large file and only overwriting a small no. of lines. Won't reading the whole file be inefficient ?@darshan

Comment: In case of large files, what you can do is, read the file line by line and simultaneously write that line to a new file. Once you encounter the line which needs to be replaced, replace it with new lines and afterwards, skip those lines and continue reading from the old file until you encounter the end. This way it won't consume more memory.

Comment: If you think my answer has helped you then, you can accept the answer as correct answer.